# Mysql server 8.0 initializing database failed

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to install MySQL 8.0.19 on my windows 10. I have an issue when trying to initializing database. It is failed with a message "may take a long time". Below is the log of configuration:

```
Beginning configuration step: Writing configuration file

Saving my.ini configuration file...
Saved my.ini configuration file.
Ended configuration step: Writing configuration file

Beginning configuration step: Updating Windows Firewall rules

Adding a Windows Firewall rule for MySQL80 on port 3306.
Attempting to add a Windows Firewall rule with command: netsh.exe advfirewall firewall add rule name="Port 3306" protocol=TCP localport=3306 dir=in action=allow
Ok.


Successfully added the Windows Firewall rule.
Adding a Windows Firewall rule for MySQL80 on port 33060.
Attempting to add a Windows Firewall rule with command: netsh.exe advfirewall firewall add rule name="Port 33060" protocol=TCP localport=33060 dir=in action=allow
Ok.


Successfully added the Windows Firewall rule.
Ended configuration step: Updating Windows Firewall rules

Beginning configuration step: Adjusting Windows service

Attempting to grant Network Service require filesystem permissions.
Granted permissions.
Adding new service
New service added
Ended configuration step: Adjusting Windows service

Beginning configuration step: Initializing database (may take a long time)

Deleting the data directory from a previous (failed) configuration...
Attempting to run MySQL Server with --initialize-insecure option...
Starting process for MySQL Server 8.0.19...
Starting process with command: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe --defaults-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini" --console --initialize-insecure=on --lower-case-table-names=1...
'NO_ZERO_DATE', 'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE' and 'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO' sql modes should be used with strict mode. They will be merged with strict mode in a future release.
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 8.0.19) initializing of server in progress as process 12572
Unable to create temporary file; errno: 2
InnoDB Database creation was aborted with error Generic error. You may need to delete the ibdata1 file before trying to start up again.
Data Dictionary initialization failed.
The newly created data directory C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Data\ by --initialize is unusable. You can remove it.
Aborting
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.19)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
Process for mysqld, with ID 12572, was run successfully and exited with code 1.
Failed to start process for MySQL Server 8.0.19.
Database initialization failed.
Ended configuration step: Initializing database (may take a long time)
```

anyone can help me with this problem?

Comment: Do you have enough space in the C drive? Do you have write-access on that path (C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0) ... ?  Did you run it as admin? What happened if you run that command again `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe --defaults-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini" --console --initialize-insecure=on --lower-case-table-names=1`? What else have you tried?

Comment: I have roughly 90gb of memory space, is it not enough? The log is from mysql installer, so it just a fresh error from the installation process. About the admin, I install it in my personal computer so I think it's not that kind of problem.